# Broken images are showing hosted in AWS

Tags: javascript, html, image, browser

I have an image (http://images.littletales.in/testingimageupload.jpeg) which is hosted in AWS, If I open it in browser tab it works fine.

If I try to set as src in img tag in dom it does not work, I also tried replacing it in  dom img tags directly.

I have set all the required permission.

In browser Tab -

[image]

In Dom -

[image]

Comment: `I have set all the required permission` - what does this mean?

Comment: check the developer tools network tab to see what's actually going on

Comment: It mean Read and Write permission.

Comment: great - write is irrelevant for an image you are trying to read, now check the developer tools networks tab and see what's loading when you go to the URL of the image directly

Comment: Yeh.. Got it .. It is requesting with Ip address and port and if I use ip in place of domian name it works.

Comment: no, it isn't - the request for an image to images.littletales.in returns text/html - in this html, there is a frameset (my god, a frameset!!! so 1990's) with an img tag whose src is as you see ... I'm surprised you didn't see TWO requests in network when trying to access the jpeg directly with your original address

Comment: Can you help to understand what is the reason why it is returning Iframe and why making call two time in new tab of a browser ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124899/discussion-between-kanchan-and-jaromanda-x).

Comment: it's how some sites prevent `image hotlinking` - look that up and you'll see what that means